# Display custom checkout field value on admin order detail section in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout, hook-woocommerce

Hello I'm trying to display the **custom checkout field** in the admin order details page. My Custom field is *`Delivery Option`* and it allows the user to pick the to pick a value from checkbox. I use the code below following the similar topics about this, but it seems something is wrong with my code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'checkout_shipping_additional_field', 20 );
function checkout_shipping_additional_field()
{
    $domain  = 'wocommerce';
    $default = 'option 1';

    echo '<tr class="additional-shipping-fields"><th>' . __('Delivery Time', $domain) . '</th><td>';

    // Add a custom checkbox field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_radio_field', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'options' => array(
            'option 1' => __('10:04 : 13:04 ', $domain),

        ),
        'default' => $default,
    ), $default );

    echo '</td></tr>';
}

//update order meta
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'gon_update_order_meta_business_address');

function gon_update_order_meta_business_address( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['custom_radio_field']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Business Address?', 
    esc_attr($_POST['custom_radio_field']));
}

// Display field value on the admin order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $delivery_time = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'Delivery Time', true );
    if( ! empty( $delivery_time ) )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery Time', 'woocommerce').': </strong> ' . $delivery_time . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some mistakes, so I have revisited your code. I have also replaced some hooks. Try the following:

```
// HERE set your the options array for your select field.
function delivery_time_options(){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    return array(
        '1' => __('10:04 : 13:04 ', $domain),
        '2' => __('14:04 : 16:04 ', $domain), // <== Added for testing
    );
}

// Display a custom select field after shipping total line
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'checkout_shipping_additional_field', 20 );
function checkout_shipping_additional_field(){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    echo '<tr class="additional-shipping-fields"><th>' . __('Delivery Time', $domain) . '</th><td>';

    // Add a custom select field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_time', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'options' => delivery_time_options(),
    ), '' );

    echo '</td></tr>';
}

// Save custom field as order meta data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_field_order_meta', 22, 2 );
function save_custom_field_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_time']) ) {
        $options    = delivery_time_options(); // Get select options array
        $option_key = esc_attr($_POST['delivery_time']); // The selected key

        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_time', $options[$option_key] ); // Save
    }
}

// Display a custom field value on the admin order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'display_custom_meta_data_in_backend_orders', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_meta_data_in_backend_orders( $order ){
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    $delivery_time = $order->get_meta('_delivery_time');
    if( ! empty( $delivery_time ) )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery Time', $domain).': </strong> ' . $delivery_time . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Your answer is great and works, thanks alot @loictheaztec. I extended it to a DRY method in case of wanting multiple fields without re-writing this functions for every field.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @LoicTheAztec answer, if you want **multiple fields without re-writing the functions for every field** ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), you can use this class (by adding it to your functions.php):

```
/**
 * Add a custom field to the woocommerce checkout page
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/52098807/
 */
class WOO_Add_Checkout_Field
{
    public function __construct($options)
    {

        $this->field_name = $options['field_name'];
        $this->label = $options['label'];
        $this->placeholder = $options['placeholder'];
        $this->required = $options['required'];

        if ($this->field_name && $this->label && $this->placeholder) {
            add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', [$this, 'customise_checkout_field']);
            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', [$this, 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta'], 10, 1);
            add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', [$this, 'display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages'], 10, 1);
        } else {
            die("Error in WOO_Add_Checkout_Field \$options: \n\n" . var_dump($options));
        }
    }
    public function customise_checkout_field($checkout)
    {
        echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field">';
        // echo '<h2>' . __('Heading') . '</h2>';
        woocommerce_form_field($this->field_name, array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => array(
                'my-field-class form-row-wide'
            ),
            'label' => $this->label,
            'placeholder' => $this->placeholder,
            'required' => $this->required,
        ), $checkout->get_value($this->field_name));
        echo '</div>';
    }

    public function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
    {
        if (!empty($_POST[$this->field_name]))
            update_post_meta($order_id, $this->field_name, $_POST[$this->field_name]);
        else
            update_post_meta($order_id, $this->field_name, 0);
    }


    public function display_custom_field_on_order_edit_pages($order)
    {
        $field = $order->get_meta($this->field_name);
        if (!empty($field)) {
            echo '<p><strong style="display:block" title="' . $this->placeholder . '">' . $this->label . ': </strong><span>';
            echo $field;
            echo '</span></p>';
        }
    }
}
```

And use it as many times as you'd like:

```
$my_custom_field_1 = new WOO_Add_Checkout_Field([
    'field_name' => 'my_custom_field_1',
    'label' => __('My First Field'),
    'placeholder' => __('Please write something in field 1...'),
    'required' => false,
]);

$my_custom_field_2 = new WOO_Add_Checkout_Field([
    'field_name' => 'my_custom_field_2',
    'label' => __('My Second Field'),
    'placeholder' => __('Please write something in field 2...'),
    'required' => false,
]);

$my_custom_field_3 = new WOO_Add_Checkout_Field([
    'field_name' => 'my_custom_field_3',
    'label' => __('My Third Field'),
    'placeholder' => __('Please write something in field 3...'),
    'required' => false,
]);

// and so on...
```

Please note:

- The custom field will show up in admin area ONLY if it was not sent empty
- You can customize this code how you like